# string.compare() function not comparing the correct string

Tags: c++, c++11

Unsure why, but when I am using `string::compare()` in my code, it is printing the opposing switch statement, rather than the one it is supposed to.

```cpp
cout<<lexeme << " ";
if(lexeme.compare("begin")){
   item = LexItem(BEGIN, "begin", linenum);
   return item;
}
if(lexeme.compare("print")){
   item = LexItem(PRINT, "print", linenum);
   return item;
}
```

I `cout` the string before I begin to compare, and even though it prints the correct string, it returns the `"print"` compare rather than the `"begin"`:

```
begin PRINT print 1
```

Has anyone run into this problem, or knows why it would be doing this?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`std::string::compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare)? What did you read about it's return value?

Comment: Can you reread the part in your C++ textbook that explains what `compare()` returns? If you do, the problem should be obvious. You are assuming that `compare()` returns a true value of some kind if the string compares as equal. This is not the case. See `compare()`'s documentation for more information. If you don't understand why a particular function or method doesn't work, it's a good idea to get in the habit of looking up its documentation and investigating it. Knowing where to find and how to read technical docs is something that every C++ developer needs to be able to do. Good luck!

Comment: Definitely have to get into that habit not only looking up but understanding the documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::string::compare()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns an `int`, where the value is:

> - negative if `*this` appears before the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order
> - zero if both character sequences compare equivalent
> - positive value if `*this` appears after the character sequence specified by the arguments, in lexicographical order

You are not accounting for that return value correctly.  You are expecting `compare()` to return a boolean, but it doesn't.

When `lexeme` is `"begin"`, `lexeme.compare("begin")` returns 0, and `lexeme.compare("print")` returns `< 0`.

In a boolean context (like an `if` statement), a non-zero integer will be treated as `true`, and a zero integer will be treated as `false`.  That is why you are getting the output you are seeing.

```cpp
cout << lexeme << " ";
if (lexeme.compare("begin")){ // 0 => false
    item = LexItem(BEGIN, "begin", linenum);
    return item;
}
if (lexeme.compare("print")){ // < 0 => true
    item = LexItem(PRINT, "print", linenum);
    return item;
}
```

Try this instead:

```cpp
cout << lexeme << " ";
if (lexeme.compare("begin") == 0){
    item = LexItem(BEGIN, "begin", linenum);
    return item;
}
if (lexeme.compare("print") == 0){
    item = LexItem(PRINT, "print", linenum);
    return item;
}
```

That being said, `std::string` has a comparison [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) implemented, you should be using that instead, eg:

```cpp
cout << lexeme << " ";
if (lexeme == "begin"){
    item = LexItem(BEGIN, "begin", linenum);
    return item;
}
if (lexeme == "print"){
    item = LexItem(PRINT, "print", linenum);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: I think the popularity of `string::compare` must be blamed on auto complete.

Comment: What happened to the days before autocomplete where people just remembered the entire Standard Library? Oh yeah. The Standard Library was a tenth the size.